# how to prevent url force access to files

Tags: php, .htaccess

After uploading a file to the server, I store the file path in the database.

http://localhost/ramseyer/apps/uploads/-d10ddbe8164659168192848723610514347.docx

Since the platform I am building has user access levels, I realize that even if the user is not logged in with authorization, a user can still access the file only if they somehow get to know the URL.

I've read many articles about path traversal but did not find answers.

Is there a way to forbid a user who tries to enter the file URL in the address bar just to access the file? Just as you forbid a user from accessing directories with htaccess ?

Comment: _"I've read many articles about path traversal but did not find answers."_ - that would probably have to do with the fact that your issue is not really a path traversal issue to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use RewriteRule like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(pdf|docx)$ download.php?file=$1&ext=$2
```

Please check the documentation here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

In the download file you should check the user credentials first and then output the file contents + headers.

```
// check credentials...

$filename = $_GET['file'] . '.' . $_GET['ext'];
$filename_url = $path_to_file . '/' . $filename;

header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"');
header("Content-Type: text/" . $_GET['ext']);
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($filename_url));

echo file_get_contents($filename_url);
```